# Hoveron CSS activates on one element only instead of all class members

Tags: html, css

I have a slideshow with two buttons for changing the slides and they need to be displayed only when you hover on them or the slideshow. Very primitive task and easy to accomplish, but that it doesn't work with both elements for some reasons...

Here's my rather primitive HTML:

```css
div.carousel:hover+.hide {
  display: inline-block !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.hide:hover {
  display: inline-block !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <img data-src="graphics/slider1.webp" />
    <img loading="lazy" data-src="graphics/slider2.webp" />
    <img loading="lazy" data-src="graphics/slider3.webp" />
    <img loading="lazy" data-src="graphics/slider4.webp" />
    <img loading="lazy" data-src="graphics/slider5.webp" />
    <img loading="lazy" data-src="graphics/slider6.webp" />
  </div>
  <button class="hide carousel-prev slider-button slider-black slider-display-left left-slider-button" style="opacity:0.1;">
 &#10094;
</button>
  <button class="hide carousel-next slider-button slider-black slider-display-right right-slider-button" style="opacity:0.1;">
&#10095;
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `:hover` only applies to the element that is being hovered.

Comment: When you hover on one button you want the other one to get shown as well?

Comment: Hi ! I don't understand, it works fine for me in a fiddle, ie on hover the button becomes "visible" :)

Comment: Added missing CSS, which doesn't appear to work.

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt that's correct. in general when I hover on the div I want the buttons to show up and that doesn't work apparently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
.carousel-container .hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.carousel-container:hover .hide {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Use those two instead of your `div.carousel:hover+.hide` and `.hide:hover`

I use the hover selector on the parent and show/hide the buttons inside it accordingly.

Comment: Apparently doesn't work at all, even though the code looks fine. Please check my updated question for more information, maybe the lack of info is the issue here

Comment: Can you provide the whole html code or at least the `.carousel` part of it? Maybe I can adjust my answer to your needs then.

Comment: Nervermind. you already did that. Sorry did not see it.

Comment: Edited my answer. Should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you trying to achieve. I hope my code is helpful to you.

```css
.hover button{
opacity:0.1;
}
.hover:hover button {
  display: inline-block !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover">
<button class="hide carousel-prev slider-button slider-black slider-display-left left-slider-button">
    &#10094;
  </button>
<button class="hide carousel-next slider-button slider-black slider-display-right right-slider-button">
    &#10095;
  </button>
  </div>
```